# Positioning of rotated longtable in apa6

Tags: longtable, apa6

I am finishing a manuscript with the apa6 package in LaTeX. Everything went fine except one thing: I need to place a **rotated longtable** at the end of the manuscript. The table itself works and has no problems but it won't move to the end of the manuscript when I remove the option `floatsintext` (all other tables in the document, however, do). I think the problem is that the longtable is situated in a `landscape`-environment, which obviously is not recognized by apa6. Replacing `landscape` with `sidewaystable` or similar things do not work. I am glad for any suggestions on how to make this wide longtable work in apa6.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt
               ,man % manuscript mode; jou man doc
               ,babel, american % language
               %,biblatex % loads biblatex or apacite
               ,a4paper % default:letter
               % ,floatsintext
               ,noextraspace %removes extra space after headings; closer to "true" double-spacing
               %,mask
               ,longtable
               %,helv % font in man mode
               %,tt   % font in man mode
               %,draftfirst
               %,draftall
               ]{apa6}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}


%% for the huge table to avoid boxes warnings
\newcommand{\rr}{\raggedright}
\newcommand{\tn}{\tabularnewline}



\title{Longtables and Me: An Endless Story}
\shorttitle{Longtables}

\author{Me}
\affiliation{MeU}

\authornote{
Empty
}



\abstract{
Empty.
}


\keywords{Empty}





\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{landscape}

\begin{ThreePartTable}

\begin{TableNotes}
\rr \footnotesize %
\textit{Note.} 
Just a TableNote to explain some stuff.
\end{TableNotes}


\begin{longtable}{p{7.3cm}
                  S[table-format = 5]
                  l
                  l
                  S[table-format = 2.2]
                  c
                  p{5cm}}

\caption{Longitudinal Studies Included in the Analysis} \\
\label{tab:studies} \\

\toprule
1st Column  & {2nd Column}  &  3rd Column   &  4th Column  &  {5th Column}  &  6th  &  7th Column\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead


\multicolumn{7}{l}{{\tablename} \thetable{} (continued)} \\[0.5ex]

\toprule
1st Column  & {2nd Column}  &  3rd Column   &  4th Column  &  {5th Column}  &  6th  &  7th Column\\
\midrule
\endhead

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry that is quite long and breaks to the next line   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr Another rather long Entry that also breaks and extends over two lines   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\


\bottomrule

\insertTableNotes

\end{longtable}

\end{ThreePartTable}
\end{landscape}


\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: can you not simply move it to the end of the source?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Maybe the reason is a longtable is *not* a float?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: This might work, although it would also require moving **all** tables and figures to the end in order of their appearance in the manuscript. On the downside, it would break the functionality of `floatsintext` which I tend to like very much when reviewing and sharing documents.

Comment: @Bernard: Thanks for this comment. apa6 has a good manual in which problems with longtables are discussed. Basically, I can get longtable to float, but not the rotated one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work, but only if you only use landscape for tables.

I'm not familiar with apa6, but I suspect that a lot of the packages you are adding are automatically loaded.  You might try commenting them out one at a time in you document and see if you get any errors.

```
\documentclass[12pt
               ,man % manuscript mode; jou man doc
               ,babel, american % language
               %,biblatex % loads biblatex or apacite
               ,a4paper % default:letter
               % ,floatsintext
               ,noextraspace %removes extra space after headings; closer to "true" double-spacing
               %,mask
               ,longtable
               %,helv % font in man mode
               %,tt   % font in man mode
               %,draftfirst
               %,draftall
               ]{apa6}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

%\usepackage{endfloat}

\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor*{landscape}{table}

%% for the huge table to avoid boxes warnings
\newcommand{\rr}{\raggedright}
\newcommand{\tn}{\tabularnewline}



\title{Longtables and Me: An Endless Story}
\shorttitle{Longtables}

\author{Me}
\affiliation{MeU}

\authornote{
Empty
}



\abstract{
Empty.
}


\keywords{Empty}





\begin{document}

\listoftables

\begin{table}[htp]
\caption{this is actually a table}
\end{table}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{landscape}

\begin{ThreePartTable}

\begin{TableNotes}
\rr \footnotesize %
\textit{Note.} 
Just a TableNote to explain some stuff.
\end{TableNotes}


\begin{longtable}{p{7.3cm}
                  S[table-format = 5]
                  l
                  l
                  S[table-format = 2.2]
                  c
                  p{5cm}}

\caption{Longitudinal Studies Included in the Analysis} \\
\label{tab:studies} \\

\toprule
1st Column  & {2nd Column}  &  3rd Column   &  4th Column  &  {5th Column}  &  6th  &  7th Column\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead


\multicolumn{7}{l}{{\tablename} \thetable{} (continued)} \\[0.5ex]

\toprule
1st Column  & {2nd Column}  &  3rd Column   &  4th Column  &  {5th Column}  &  6th  &  7th Column\\
\midrule
\endhead

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry that is quite long and breaks to the next line   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr Another rather long Entry that also breaks and extends over two lines   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\


\bottomrule

\insertTableNotes

\end{longtable}

\end{ThreePartTable}
\end{landscape}

\hrule
\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```