# How to format a long table overstretching portrait page width to landscape format?

Tags: tables, rotating

In my new paper (using double-column format), I have a long table that overstretches the page width (even combining both columns) in the current portrait format, and some reviewers suggested that I may format the table in the landscape format for readability. (There are many parameters in the system and this causes the long table with several columns in the performance analysis).

I have enclosed my code below. Any help to put it in landscape format is highly appreciated.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
 \caption{Dynamics, LCE and $D_L$ of the 4-D System (1)}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|p{1.4cm}|p{1.4cm}|p{1.6cm}|p{1.4cm}|p{1.6cm}|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Dynamics} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Parameters} &  Bifurcation   Parameter  & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{LCE} & \multirow{2}{*}{$D_{L}$ }  \\
  \cline{2-5} \cline{7-10}
  & $a$ & $b$ & $c$ &  $d$  & &$\tau_1$ & $\tau_2 $& $\tau_3$ & $\tau_4$ &   \\[2mm] \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Periodic} & $[30, 33.9$], $[34.5,34.7]$    & $28$ & $4$   & $7$ &  $a = 31$  & $ 0$  & $ -0.150$  &  $-3.421$  & $-3.429$  &  $0 $  \\[2mm]
  \cline{2-11}
 &  $40$   & $[8, 14.4]$, $[20.9, 21.7]$ &  $4$  & $7$  &  $b = 10$  & $ 0$  & $ -0.190$  &  $-1.222$  & $ -32.587$  &  $0 $  \\[2mm]
   \cline{2-11}
 &  $40$   & $28$&$[0.01, 0.12]$, $[3.14, 3.27]$    &7  &  $c = 0.08$  & $ 0$  & $ -0.085$  &  $-0.454$  &
   $ -11.538$  &  $0 $  \\[2mm]
     \cline{2-11}
 & $40$    & $28$ & $4$   & $[3.8, 4.4]$ &  $d = 4.26$  & $ 0$  & $ -0.549$  &  $-3.668$  & $ 0.812$  &  $0 $  \\[2mm]    \hline
 Quasi-periodic & $[34.2, 34.5]$ & $28$ & $4$ & $7$ & $a=34.3$ & $0$ & $0$ & $-1.355$ & $-8.950$ & $0$ \\[2mm]
 \hline
 \multirow{4}{*}{Chaos} & $[33.9, 34.2]$, $[34.5,34.7]$    & $28$ & $4$   & $7$ &  $a = 34.1$  &
 $ 0.063$  & $ 0$  &  $-0.708$  & $-9.457$  &  $2.089 $  \\[2mm]
  \cline{2-11}
 &  $40$   & $[21.7, 22]$ &  $4$  & $7$  &  $b = 21.9$  & $ 0.111$  & $0$  &  $-0.027$  & $ -22.185$  &  $3.004 $  \\[2mm]
   \cline{2-11}
 &  $40$   & $28$&$[0.12, 0.3]$, $[3.05, 3.14]$    &7  &  $c = 0.2$  & $ 0.069$  & $ 0$  &  $-0.078$  &
   $ -12.191$  &  $2.885 $  \\[2mm]
     \cline{2-11}
 & $40$    & $28$ & $4$   & $[0, 0.9]$, $[3.4, 3.8]$ &  $d = 3.5$  & $ 0.147$  & $ 0$  &  $-0.033$  & $ -16.115$  &  $3.007 $  \\[2mm]    \hline
 \multirow{4}{*}{Hyperchaos} & $[35, 40]$    & $28$ & $4$   & $7$ &  $a = 38$  &
 $ 2.736$  & $0.135$  &  $0$  & $-16.873$  &  $3.170$  \\[2mm]
  \cline{2-11}
 &  $40$   & $[14.4,20.9]$, $[22,28]$ &  $4$  & $7$  &  $b = 18$  & $ 0.683$  & $0.385$  &  $0$  & $ -27.070$  &  $3.039 $  \\[2mm]
   \cline{2-11}
 &  $40$   & $28$&$[0.3,3.05]$, $[3.27,4]$    &7  &  $c = 3.5$  & $ 3.049$  & $ 0.146$  &  $0$  &
   $ -18.699$  &  $3.171 $  \\[2mm]
     \cline{2-11}
 & $40$    & $28$ & $4$   & $[0.9,3.4]$, $[4.4,7]$ &  $d = 3$  & $3.151$  & $ 0.046$  & $0$  & $ -219.201$  &  $3.166 $  \\[2mm]    \hline

\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

My LaTeX output enclosed below..[image: LaTeX output]

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380024/positioning-of-rotated-longtable-in-apa6 .  There are several related questions, but they are generally more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many journals  will not accept a landscape page but will allow you to put a landscape table on a portrait page.

**Option 1** Use the table from your question, with minor changes, and rotate a `minipage` containing the table. Of course, floats are neither allowed nor required, so `\captionof{table}{<text >}` is used to insert the caption.
[image: a]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx} % rotatebox <<<<<
\usepackage{caption}% captionof <<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % only for dummy text

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}% to center p columns
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
    
1.  \kant[1-3]
    
\clearpage  
\hspace*{\dimexpr-\columnwidth-\columnsep}\rotatebox{90}{% 
\begin{minipage}{\textheight}
        \centering%
        \captionof{table}{Dynamics, LCE and $D_L$ of the 4-D System (1)}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|C{1.5cm}|C{1.5cm}|C{1.5cm}|C{1.5cm}|C{1.8cm}|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline % changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \multirow{2}[6]{*}{Dynamics} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Parameters} &  Bifurcation Parameter & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{LCE} & \multirow{2}{*}{$D_{L}$ }  \\
        \cline{2-5} \cline{7-10}
        & $a$ & $b$ & $c$ &  $d$  & &$\tau_1$ & $\tau_2 $& $\tau_3$ & $\tau_4$ &   \\[2mm] \hline
        \multirow{4}[12]{*}{Periodic} & $[30, 33.9$], $[34.5,34.7]$    & $28$ & $4$   & $7$ &  $a = 31$  & $ 0$  & $ -0.150$  &  $-3.421$  & $-3.429$  &  $0 $  \\[2mm]
        \cline{2-11}
        &  $40$   & $[8, 14.4]$, $[20.9, 21.7]$ &  $4$  & $7$  &  $b = 10$  & $ 0$  & $ -0.190$  &  $-1.222$  & $ -32.587$  &  $0 $  \\[2mm]
        \cline{2-11}
        &  $40$   & $28$&$[0.01, 0.12]$, $[3.14, 3.27]$    &7  &  $c = 0.08$  & $ 0$  & $ -0.085$  &  $-0.454$  &
        $ -11.538$  &  $0 $  \\[2mm]
        \cline{2-11}
        & $40$    & $28$ & $4$   & $[3.8, 4.4]$ &  $d = 4.26$  & $ 0$  & $ -0.549$  &  $-3.668$  & $ 0.812$  &  $0 $  \\[2mm]    \hline
        Quasi-periodic & $[34.2, 34.5]$ & $28$ & $4$ & $7$ & $a=34.3$ & $0$ & $0$ & $-1.355$ & $-8.950$ & $0$ \\[2mm]
        \hline
        \multirow{4}[10]{*}{Chaos} & $[33.9, 34.2]$, $[34.5,34.7]$    & $28$ & $4$   & $7$ &  $a = 34.1$  &
        $ 0.063$  & $ 0$  &  $-0.708$  & $-9.457$  &  $2.089 $  \\[2mm]
        \cline{2-11}
        &  $40$   & $[21.7, 22]$ &  $4$  & $7$  &  $b = 21.9$  & $ 0.111$  & $0$  &  $-0.027$  & $ -22.185$  &  $3.004 $  \\[2mm]
        \cline{2-11}
        &  $40$   & $28$&$[0.12, 0.3]$, $[3.05, 3.14]$    &7  &  $c = 0.2$  & $ 0.069$  & $ 0$  &  $-0.078$  &
        $ -12.191$  &  $2.885 $  \\[2mm]
        \cline{2-11}
        & $40$    & $28$ & $4$   & $[0, 0.9]$, $[3.4, 3.8]$ &  $d = 3.5$  & $ 0.147$  & $ 0$  &  $-0.033$  & $ -16.115$  &  $3.007 $  \\[2mm]    \hline
        \multirow{4}[10]{*}{Hyperchaos} & $[35, 40]$    & $28$ & $4$   & $7$ &  $a = 38$  &
        $ 2.736$  & $0.135$  &  $0$  & $-16.873$  &  $3.170$  \\[2mm]
        \cline{2-11}
        &  $40$   & $[14.4,20.9]$, $[22,28]$ &  $4$  & $7$  &  $b = 18$  & $ 0.683$  & $0.385$  &  $0$  & $ -27.070$  &  $3.039 $  \\[2mm]
        \cline{2-11}
        &  $40$   & $28$&$[0.3,3.05]$, $[3.27,4]$    &7  &  $c = 3.5$  & $ 3.049$  & $ 0.146$  &  $0$  &
        $ -18.699$  &  $3.171 $  \\[2mm]
        \cline{2-11}
        & $40$    & $28$ & $4$   & $[0.9,3.4]$, $[4.4,7]$ &  $d = 3$  & $3.151$  & $ 0.046$  & $0$  & $ -219.201$  &  $3.166 $  \\[2mm]    \hline           
    \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
}
\clearpage

2. \kant[4-6]
\end{document}
```

**Option 2** Same technique but now using the nicely formatted table from Zarko's answer.

[image: c]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{report}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

\usepackage{graphicx} % rotatebox
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % only for dummy text

\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
    
1.  \kant[1-3]
    
    \clearpage  
    \hspace*{\dimexpr-\columnwidth-\columnsep}\rotatebox{90}{%    
    \begin{minipage}{\textheight}
        \centering
        \begin{talltblr}[
        caption = {Dynamics, LCE and $D_L$ of the 4-D System (1)},
        label = {tab:???} ]{
            hlines, vlines,
            colspec = {*{5}{X[c, m]}
                X[c, mode=math]
                Q[c, si={table-format=1.3}]
                Q[c, si={table-format=-1.3}]
                Q[c, si={table-format=-1.3}]
                Q[c, si={table-format=-3.3}]
                Q[c, si={table-format=1.3}]},
            colsep=3pt, 
            row{2} = {mode=math, c}
        }
        \SetCell[r=2]{c}    Dynamics    
        & \SetCell[c=4]{c}  Parameters
        &   &   &   &   \SetCell[r=2]{c, mode=text}    {{{Bifurcation   Parameter}}}  
        & \SetCell[c=4]{c}  {{{LCE}}}
        &   &   &   &   \SetCell[r=2]{c}    {{{$D_{L}$}}}   \\
        & a & b & c & d &   & {{{\tau_1}}} 
        & {{{\tau_2}}}
        & {{{\tau_3}}}
        & {{{\tau_4}}}
        &       \\      
        \SetCell[r=4]{c}    Periodic    & [30, 33.9], [34.5,34.7]   & 28    & 4 & 7 & a = 31    & 0 & -0.150    & -3.421        &  -3.429       & 0     \\
                                        & 40    & [8, 14.4], [20.9, 21.7]   & 4 & 7 & b = 10    & 0 & -0.190    & -1.222        & -32.587       & 0     \\ 
                                        & 40    & 28    & [0.01, 0.12], [3.14, 3.27]        & 7 &  c = 0.08     & 0 & -0.085    & -0.454    & -11.538   & 0  \\ 
                                        & 40    & 28    & 4 & [3.8, 4.4]& d = 4.26  & 0 & -0.549        & -3.668    & 0.812 & 0  \\
        \SetCell[r=4]{c}Quasi-periodic  & [34.2, 34.5]  & 28    & 4 & 7 & a = 34.3      & 0 & 0 & -1.355    & -8.950        & 0 \\
        \SetCell[r=4]{c}    Chaos       & [33.9, 34.2], [34.5,34.7]     & 28    & 4 & 7 & a = 34.1      & 0.063     & 0 & -0.708    & -9.457    & 2.089 \\
                                        & 40    & [21.7, 22]    & 4 & 7 & b = 21.9      & 0.111     & 0 & -0.027        & -22.185       & 3.004 \\ 
                                        & 40    & 28    &[0.12, 0.3], [3.05, 3.14]      & 7 & c = 0.2   & 0.069     & 0 & -0.078    & -12.191   & 2.885 \\
                                        & 40    & 28    & 4 & [0, 0.9], [3.4, 3.8]  & d = 3.5       & 0.147     & 0 & -0.033    & -16.115       & 3.007 \\
        \SetCell[r=4]{c}    Hyperchaos  & [35, 40]  & 28    & 4 & 7 & a = 38    & 2.736 & 0.135     & 0 & -16.873       & 3.170 \\
                                        & 40    & [14.4,20.9], [22,28]  & 4 & 7 & b = 18    & 0.683     & 0.385     & 0 & -27.070   & 3.039 \\
                                        & 40    & 28    & [0.3,3.05], [3.27,4]      & 7 & c = 3.5   & 3.049     & 0.146     & 0 & -18.699       & 3.171 \\
                                        & 40    & 28    & 4 & [0.9,3.4], [4.4,7]    & d = 3 & 3.151     & 0.046     & 0 & -219.201      & 3.166 \\
    \end{talltblr}
\end{minipage}
}
\clearpage

2. \kant[4-6]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

- You should load `lscape` or `pdflscape` package in your document preamble.
- In columns with math expressions should be in math mode.
  In columns with numbers (the last five) I would use `S` columns (defined in the `siunitx` package).
- With use of the `tabularray` package code is shorter:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
    \begin{talltblr}[
caption = {Dynamics, LCE and $D_L$ of the 4-D System (1)},
  label = {tab:???} ]{
            hlines, vlines,
            colspec = {*{5}{X[l, m]}
                            X[l, mode=math]
                            Q[c, si={table-format=1.3}]
                            Q[c, si={table-format=-1.3}]
                            Q[c, si={table-format=-1.3}]
                            Q[c, si={table-format=-3.3}]
                            Q[c, si={table-format=1.3}]},
            colsep=3pt,
            row{2} = {mode=math, c}
                      }
\SetCell[r=2]{c}    Dynamics    
    & \SetCell[c=4]{c}  Parameters
        &   &   &   &   \SetCell[r=2]{c, mode=text}    {{{Bifurcation   Parameter}}}  
                        & \SetCell[c=4]{c}  {{{LCE}}}
                            &   &   &   &   \SetCell[r=2]{c}    {{{$D_{L}$}}}   \\
    & a & b & c & d &   & {{{\tau_1}}} 
                            & {{{\tau_2}}}
                                & {{{\tau_3}}}
                                    & {{{\tau_4}}}
                                        &       \\      
\SetCell[r=4]{l}    Periodic
    & [30, 33.9], [34.5,34.7]    
        & 28 
            & 4 & 7 & a = 31    
                        & 0 & -0.150   
                                & -3.421    
                                    &  -3.429   
                                        & 0     \\
    & 40   
        & [8, 14.4], [20.9, 21.7] 
            & 4 & 7 & b = 10    
                        & 0 & -0.190   
                                & -1.222    
                                    & -32.587   
                                        & 0     \\ 
    &  40   
        & 28
            & [0.01, 0.12], [3.14, 3.27]    
                & 7 &  c = 0.08 
                        & 0 & -0.085   
                                & -0.454   
                                    & -11.538    
                                        & 0     \\
     \cline{2-11}
    & 40    
        & 28 
            & 4 & [3.8, 4.4] 
                    & d = 4.26  
                        & 0 & -0.549    
                                & -3.668 
                                    & 0.812
                                        & 0  \\
Quasi-periodic 
    & [34.2, 34.5] 
        & 28 
            & 4 & 7 & a = 34.3  
                        & 0 & 0 & -1.355    
                                    & -8.950    
                                        & 0 \\
\SetCell[r=4]{l}    Chaos
    & [33.9, 34.2], [34.5,34.7]    
        & 28 
            & 4 & 7 & a = 34.1  
                        & 0.063  
                            & 0 & -0.708
                                    & -9.457 
                                        & 2.089 \\
    &  40       
        & [21.7, 22] 
            & 4 & 7 & b = 21.9  
                        & 0.111  
                            & 0 & -0.027    
                                    & -22.185   
                                        & 3.004 \\ 
    &  40   
        & 28
            &[0.12, 0.3], [3.05, 3.14]    
                & 7 & c = 0.2   
                        & 0.069  
                            & 0 & -0.078
                                    & -12.191
                                        & 2.885 \\
    & 40    
        & 28 
            & 4 & [0, 0.9], [3.4, 3.8] 
                    & d = 3.5   
                        & 0.147  
                            & 0 & -0.033
                                    & -16.115   
                                        & 3.007 \\
\SetCell[r=4]{l}    Hyperchaos
    & [35, 40]    
        & 28 
            & 4 & 7 & a = 38    
                        & 2.736
                            & 0.135  
                                & 0 & -16.873   
                                        & 3.170 \\
    &  40   
        & [14.4,20.9], [22,28] 
            & 4 & 7 & b = 18    
                        & 0.683  
                            & 0.385  
                                & 0 & -27.070
                                        & 3.039 \\
    &  40   
        & 28
            & [0.3,3.05], [3.27,4]    
                & 7 & c = 3.5
                        & 3.049  
                            & 0.146     
                                & 0 & -18.699   
                                        & 3.171 \\
    & 40    
        & 28 
            & 4 & [0.9,3.4], [4.4,7] 
                    & d = 3
                        & 3.151  
                            & 0.046  
                                & 0 & -219.201  
                                        & 3.166 \\
\end{talltblr}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]